# The content of element type "result" must match "(module-dependency|package-dependency|token- dependency)"

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic

WebLogic 10.3.6
Java 1.6

So I'm getting an XML problem using Eclipse. Before I went on vacation 7 days ago, this was working fine. I actually reverted to an older version before I left because I got too far ahead with something that isn't very important atm.  I get back today, and I can't get rid of this problem:

> The content of element type "result" must match "(module-dependency|package-dependency|token-  dependency)".

This is from a jdk that I have been using on this site for months. In a file that I have never looked at before, let alone changed.  The file is in the jdk at jdk160_29/lib/visualvm/platform/config/ModuleAutoDeps/org-openide-modules.xml. Here is the file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
DO NOT ALTER OR REMOVE COPYRIGHT NOTICES OR THIS HEADER.

Copyright 1997-2010 Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle and Java are registered trademarks of Oracle and/or its affiliates.
Other names may be trademarks of their respective owners.


The contents of this file are subject to the terms of either the GNU
General Public License Version 2 only ("GPL") or the Common
Development and Distribution License("CDDL") (collectively, the
"License"). You may not use this file except in compliance with the
License. You can obtain a copy of the License at
http://www.netbeans.org/cddl-gplv2.html
or nbbuild/licenses/CDDL-GPL-2-CP. See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations under the
License.  When distributing the software, include this License Header
Notice in each file and include the License file at
nbbuild/licenses/CDDL-GPL-2-CP.  Oracle designates this
particular file as subject to the "Classpath" exception as provided
by Oracle in the GPL Version 2 section of the License file that
accompanied this code. If applicable, add the following below the
License Header, with the fields enclosed by brackets [] replaced by
your own identifying information:
"Portions Copyrighted [year] [name of copyright owner]"

Contributor(s):

The Original Software is NetBeans. The Initial Developer of the Original
Software is Sun Microsystems, Inc. Portions Copyright 1997-2006 Sun
Microsystems, Inc. All Rights Reserved.

If you wish your version of this file to be governed by only the CDDL
or only the GPL Version 2, indicate your decision by adding
"[Contributor] elects to include this software in this distribution
under the [CDDL or GPL Version 2] license." If you do not indicate a
single choice of license, a recipient has the option to distribute
your version of this file under either the CDDL, the GPL Version 2 or
to extend the choice of license to its licensees as provided above.
However, if you add GPL Version 2 code and therefore, elected the GPL
Version 2 license, then the option applies only if the new code is
made subject to such option by the copyright holder.
-->

<!DOCTYPE transformations PUBLIC "-//NetBeans//DTD Module Automatic Dependencies 1.0//EN" "http://www.netbeans.org/dtds/module-auto-deps-1_0.dtd">

<transformations version="1.0">
    <transformationgroup>
        <description>openide.jar split into smaller parts. See http://openide.netbeans.org/proposals/arch/modularize.html and use 'ant fix-dependencies' if your project is projectized.</description>
        <exclusion codenamebase="org.openide.loaders" prefix="false"/>
        <!--
        <exclusion codenamebase="org.netbeans.core" prefix="true"/>
        -->
        <transformation>
            <trigger-dependency type="cancel">
                <module-dependency codenamebase="org.openide" major="1" spec="6.0"/>
            </trigger-dependency>
            <implies>
                <result>
                    <module-dependency codenamebase="org.openide.filesystems" spec="6.0"/>
                    <module-dependency codenamebase="org.openide.util" spec="6.0"/>
                    <module-dependency codenamebase="org.openide.util.enumerations" spec="6.0"/>
                    <module-dependency codenamebase="org.openide.modules" spec="6.0"/>
                    <module-dependency codenamebase="org.openide.nodes" spec="6.0"/>
                    <module-dependency codenamebase="org.openide.explorer" spec="6.0"/>
                    <module-dependency codenamebase="org.openide.awt" spec="6.0"/>
                    <module-dependency codenamebase="org.openide.dialogs" spec="6.0"/>
                    <module-dependency codenamebase="org.openide.compat" spec="6.0"/>
                    <module-dependency codenamebase="org.openide.options" spec="6.0"/>
                    <module-dependency codenamebase="org.openide.windows" spec="6.0"/>
                    <module-dependency codenamebase="org.openide.text" spec="6.0"/>
                    <module-dependency codenamebase="org.openide.actions" spec="6.0"/>
                    <!-- better to include this as well, as people sometimes forget to specify dep on loaders -->
                    <module-dependency codenamebase="org.openide.loaders" spec="5.3"/>
                </result>
            </implies>
        </transformation>
    </transformationgroup>

</transformations>
```

Help would be awesome. So would no random errors popping up out of nowhere, but that's Eclipse I guess...

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really have anything to do with Eclipse. The error message is telling you that the DTD specifies `result` as allowing a single child element, and you clearly have way more than that.

Comment: Do you know why this error just came to be? I've ran this site/application tons of times before (and even right before I left for vacation) with no problems. Then I come back from vacation and this happens...